# Case Creator unable to view case once case ownership changes to queue

Tags: case, sharing-rule, owd

This seems basic but I cannot figure out how to do this. Here are my requirements:

1. When a User submits a  developer issue case, the case gets assigned to the developer issue queue (Complete. done by process builder)
2. The User should be able to view all developer issues in a list view (Created Sharing Rule to see all developer issue cases - done)
3. The User should be able to view their own cases in a list view

Point 3 is where I need help. Our OWD for Case is Private/Private. So when the Case Owner changes to the Queue, the user is no longer able to see their cases. There has to be a way for the case creator to see their cases, even if the Owner is now a queue?

This all happens on a Community page if that's important. Everyone accessing the page is an internal user.

Comment: Are you referring to the standard `My Cases` list view here when you say *their cases*?

Comment: @JayantDas I was thinking to create a 'My Developer Cases' list view here.

Comment: You will need to put correct filter criteria on your list view to be able to view such cases where the User is not the Owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the Created user is not part of the QUEUE. So, it is the reason that they cannot see the case just created .

Some solutions:

1. Create a Process Builder on Case Object (only when it is created) that call a Flow inserting Case Team Member. The CreatedBy should be part of Case Team Member with Readonly Access
2. Create a trigger that insert Case Team Member using the same approach

Comment: That's right. The created users are not apart of the Developer Case Queue.

Comment: I may need to go this route. We use Flows instead of triggers.  Could I create a flow that populates the Case Creator as a Team Member with Read only access and call the flow in my Process Builder in my requirement #1?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can create Process Builder that will call a Visual Flow.

Answer (score 0):

> So when the Case Owner changes to the Queue, the user is no longer able to see their cases. There has to be a way for the case creator to see their cases, even if the Owner is now a queue?

The reason the User is most likely not able to view the Cases in that list view is because of the filter criteria. *Their Cases* is relevant in the context where a User is actually an Owner of the Case and is working on it.

In your scenario though, the functionality you seem to be looking for is to allow a User who *created* a Case to be able to view all such Cases, even if the Owner is a Queue. If this is what you are looking for, you can just edit or create a list view and add a condition in that list view irrespective of who owns the Case, as long as the User has access to the Case.

As an example, this is how I can configure/edit a list view to include all such cases which are assigned to a Queue but Created by Me.

[image]

Which gives me the result as:

[image]

Comment: This approach works but would each user need to create their own list view where created by equals their alias name? We have over 5k users and wouldn't want the responsibility of creating the list view to be on them.

Comment: If you want individual created by users to be able to view records in this manner, then yes. **Because** the value in the filter criteria will be respective to those users. You cannot create a *dynamic* list view in this case.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was afraid of.  You can't use merge fields, for example, as the values in a list view criteria to make it dynamic.